# Pandas dataframe filter n subsequent rows after certain column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
       Sentence #           Word     Tag
0     Sentence: 1           This       O
1             NaN             is       O
2             NaN              a       x
3             NaN           test       O
4     Sentence: 2           This       O
5             NaN             is       x
6             NaN        another       x
7             NaN           test       O
...
```

I would like to group it by sentence, e.g. return:

```
[['This is a test'], ['This is another test'], ...]
```

And also get a list of all words tagged with 'x' for every sentence, e.g.:

```
[['a'], ['is', 'another'], ...]
```

I have been trying to find ways to do this with no success using group(). What is the best way to solve it? Thanks

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.fillna.html - might help

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I used:

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

to propagate non-null values forward. Then i computed sentences with:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Sentence #')['Word'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
```

To get tagged words:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Sentence #', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g[g['Tag'] == 'x'])
df2 = df2.groupby('Sentence #')['Word'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Not sure if it's the most efficient solution though.